# How to select a variable from JSONP statement

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsonp

I have the following Ajax that uses the Wikipedia API to return a jsonp result for Bon Jovi:

```
var wikiUrl = 'Bon_Jovi';

function getAbout(wikiUrl){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=&titles=' + wikiUrl,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

The data response is as follows:

```
>Object {warnings: Object, query: Object}
   >query: Object
      >normalized: Array[1]
      >pages: Object
         >63123: Object
            >extract: "<p><b>Bon Jovi</b> is an American rock band...</p>"
```

How can I select the `extract` and save it as a string? `var extractText = data.query.pages[0].extract` returns `query` as an undefined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pages` is an object, not an array. In this case, the data is under the `63123` property. Unless you know this property before-hand, you would need to iterate over the properties.

### Example:

```
var wikiUrl = 'Bon_Jovi';
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=&titles=' + wikiUrl,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
      var pages = data.query.pages;
      for (var p in pages) {
        if(pages.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
          console.log(pages[p].extract);
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```js
var extractText = data.query.pages[63123].extract
```